# Add multiple Push notifications to Global Array ios

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, push

I have a problem handling more than one Push Notifications. When I unlock the iphone and there is (for example) 10 push notifications of my app, my app just register some:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:         (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
if (launchOptions != nil)
{
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    if (dictionary != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary);
        [self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:dictionary updateUI:YES];
    }


       }
   }
```

If my app is open there is no problem and all received notifications are added to array.
Thank you